# How can I add a jump to the player controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to jump by pressing on space key inside a place like home or space station and also outside.

This is the player controller script attached to a capsule :

It was working fine until I added the jump part. At the top I added this 3 lines :

```
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
public float gravity = 20.0F;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
```

Then in the Update added :

```
if (controller.isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```

But I don't have the variable controller.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;

    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        float straffe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;

        translation *= Time.deltaTime;
        straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translation);

        if (controller.isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the cam mouse look script attached to the main camera that is child of the capsule :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamMouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;

    Vector2 mouseLook;
    Vector2 smoothV;

    GameObject character;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        character = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);

        mouseLook += smoothV;

        mouseLook.y = Mathf.Clamp(mouseLook.y, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
        character.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, character.transform.up);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about applying a force?

```
public Rigidbody myphysic;
public float forceofjump = 100f; // or minor or more....

void Awake()
{
    myphysic= transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (controller.isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
        myphysic.AddForce( transform.up * forceofjump, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Vector3.zero is wrong beacouse set all movement vector to zero! so = no actions!

or, exemple:

```
Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
```

what does it mean:

new Vector3(X=stop, Y=10 of force, Z=stop);

Comment: moveDirection is based on translete, not force. So you "dragging" on axis the object.
In order to have a realistic leap you have to tie yourself to the physics of the object.

So use an [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

Comment: It does nothing. And where is the Input "Jump" ?

Comment: @BenBenShmil I updated the example. Just apply a little logic.

One more thing: One more thing: Obviously you have to apply a value to forceofjump and you have to recover the rigidbody, therefore you have to apply it to the gameobject.